# Crear una Notificación que aparezca un día determinado

Tags: java, android

tengo esta notificación que me funciona cuando pulso un botón, pero lo que quiero es que se active un determinado día, a una hora concreta o cuando enciendan el móvil, esto de al encenderse lo he visto en algunos juegos.

Este es el código que tengo:

```html
 int notificationID = 1;
  
   protected void displayNotification(){
  Intent i = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
  i.putExtra("notificationID", notificationID);
  
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);
  NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  
  CharSequence ticker ="¡¡Nuevos acertijos te esperan!!";
  CharSequence contentTitle = "Nombre del juego";
  CharSequence contentText = "¡¡Visita ahora nuestro juego!!";
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
  Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setTicker(ticker)
        .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
        .setContentText(contentText)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setLargeIcon(bm)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, ticker, pendingIntent)
        .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 250, 100, 500})
        .build();
  nm.notify(notificationID, noti);
 }
```

y luego otro archivo llamado NotificacionView.java con este código

```html
public class NotificationView extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  // Cancelamos la Notificacion que hemos comenzado
  nm.cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("notificationID"));
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes configurar una alarma con AlarmManager, esto debe ir de la mano con un Broadcast Receiver para volver a configurar la alarma, ya que si el dispositivo se apaga, pierde la configuración.

Ahora vamos con el código para generar la alarma.

1º Generar un broadcast que será invocado cuando se lance la alarma

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //Aquí podrías lanzar tu notificación...
}
```

}

2º Añadimos al manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

3º Lanzamos la alarma

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 8000;

```
    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

Esto es un ejemplo básico para poder lanzar una notificación con una alarma o cuando se inicie el dispositivo. Desde luego puede haber más formas.

Saludos.

Comment: jsancheh algún día ese link que proporciona puede desaparecer, lo mejor es copiar ya sea el ejemplo o la explicación de ese enlace aquí y hacer referencia solamente para obtener más información, estaría súper si editas tu respuesta y detallas muy bien :)

Comment: jsancheh, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
**[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.

Comment: Hola a todos, gracias por las indicaciones pero no estoy de acuerdo con generar un código o ejemplo completo de algo que está sumamente documentado ya que al final lo que se consigue es que los desarrolladores más novel copien y peguen sin sentido. Estoy de acuerdo en poner trozos de código de algo muy concreto. Con esto no quiero generar polémica, espero ayudar. Saludos a todos.